# How to parse the Info.plist file from an ipa

Tags: ios, parsing, ipa

I want to write a program to get app details, e.g. app name, version, bundle identifier, from an ipa file. However this file is not a plain text file, it's encoded in some way and my program cannot parse it.

Is there any way to decode this file?

**UPDATE**

To clarify the question, I'm writing a python program to get app details from ipa files that I exported from Xcode.

Comment: Clarify your question. Are you talking about getting details from the app's own Info.plist or are you talking about an app that can extract the Info.plist info of other ipa files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those without Apple Developer logins, here's the two answers from the accepted answer's [link](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1076090) (you have to login to see it):

- use `PlistBuddy`

  - `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleIdentifier" yourBinaryOrXmlPlist.plist`
- There are also many other ways to parse binary plist files. For example, I'm using Python and there is a library called biplist, which is exactly used to read and write binary plist files and support both Python 2 and 3. Also, the 'plistlib' in Python 3.4 supports binary plist manipulation with new APIs.

Answer (score 10):

It's easy if you have a macbook.
Then follow this guideline: http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/07/extract-and-explore-an-ios-app-in-mac-os-x/

1. Rename from file.ipa -> file.zip
2. Unzip file.zip
3. Go to Payload folder
4. Right click Application file -> Show Package Contents
5. See Info.plist

Answer (score 2):

My Python version:
https://gist.github.com/noamtm/a8ddb994df41583b64f8

In my research, the tricky bit was parsing a binary plist, since python's PlistLib can't read it:

```
from Foundation import NSData, NSPropertyListSerialization 
# Use PyObjC, pre-installed in Apple's Python dist.
def parse_plist(info_plist_string):
  data = NSData.dataWithBytes_length_(info_plist_string, len(info_plist_string))
  return NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData_options_format_error_(data, 0, None, None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the script that is very helpful for reading plist without knowing the app name +1

Answer (score 2):

A double click on the plist will open from XCode.

Answer (score 1):

Got the [answer](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1076090) from the Apple's developer forum:

> PlistBuddy is what you're looking for:
>
> `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c  "Print :CFBundleIdentifier" yourBinaryOrXmlPlist.plist`

Comment: this kind of answer is not helpful to the community, it's possible that the link will not always work.

Answer (score 1):

On a mac you can do it with the ootb [**`plutil`**](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/plutil/):

```sh
# Convert a binary plist to XML
plutil -convert xml1 info.plist
 
# Convert XML back to binary
plutil -convert binary1 info.plist
```

For more details enter `man plutil` in the terminal.

If you want to parse a text or binary `.plist` file programatically, for example with python, then you can use `plistlib` — a standard library module:

```py
import plistlib

with open ('/etc/bootpd.plist', 'rb') as plist:
    conf = plistlib.load(plist)
    print(conf['dhcp_enabled'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i found out in python :
Since .plist files are binary-encoded so, you will need a python libary that could read files with binary format. For this particular example i use **plistlib**.
NOTE: You get .app file when you unzip .ipa file.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile 
import plistlib 
with ZipFile("/content/sample_data/Experience Abu Dhabi.app.zip", 'r') as zObject: 
zObject.extractall( 
    path="/content/sample_data/temp") 
path = "/content/sample_data/temp/Experience Abu Dhabi.app/Info.plist"
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    data = plistlib.load(f)
print(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Rename from file.ipa -> file.zip
2. Unzip file.zip Go to Payload folder
3. Right click Application file -> Show Package Contents
4. Right click 'Info.plist' using xcode